# How to scroll a table horizontally?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a table built from a dataset that is displayed in a partial view. The table is larger than the bowser.

How can I get the table to scroll horizontally in my partial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
<div style="width: 700px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One minor quibble overflow-x is a CSS3 property so not valid CSS2.1.  If you define a width but **not** a height on a container div and then declare overflow:auto; then vertically the div will stretch but horizontally you will get a scroll bar.

so from the example in the answer above mine:

```
<div style="width: 700px; overflow: auto;">
       <table>...</table>
</div>
```